# Android - How to use Volley HTTP Post with element tags in body

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

I have been trying to figure out how to use Volley with HTML element tags in the body, but could use some help.

As an example, for the API that I am using, the required format to create a user with a POST is like the below:

```
{
    "username":"",
    "password":"",
    "email":"someone@example.invalid",
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "phone_number":"202-555-0113",
    "address":"123 Road Name",
    "city":"Jamesetown",
    "state":"AZ",
    "postal_code":"12345",
    "country":"United States",
}
```

...which I was able to format on the Android side and successfully handle the POST like the below:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

    Map<String, String> bodyKeyValue = new HashMap<>();

    bodyKeyValue.put("username", accountName);               
    bodyKeyValue.put("password", accountPassword);           
    bodyKeyValue.put("email", email);                        
    bodyKeyValue.put("first_name", first);                   
    bodyKeyValue.put("last_name", last);   
    // etc.                  

    return new JSONObject(bodyKeyValue).toString().getBytes();
}
```

However, when it comes to the POST needing to be formatted with element tags, I can't seem to figure out how that would be formatted in my Volley body. How can I fit this into a MAP object? In any response, could you please also inform me if the getBodyContentType needs to be changed as well? The header content-type should remain the same. Thank you!

```
<sci_request version="1.2">
  <data_service>
    <targets>
      <device id="1234-5678" />
    </targets>
   <requests>
     <device_request target_name="myTarget"> 
       some request string value
     </device_request>
   </requests>
  </data_service>
</sci_request>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be much easier than expected... Just change the body as follows:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

    String data =
                "<sci_request version=\"1.2\">" +
                "<data_service>" +
                "<targets>" +
                "<device id=\"1234-5678\" />" +
                "</targets>" +
                "<requests>" +
                "<device_request target_name=\"myTarget\">" +
                "some request string value" +
                "</device_request>" +
                "</requests>" +
                "</data_service>" +
                "</sci_request>";
             
    return data.getBytes();
}
```

It should be noted that this is a Volley StringRequest and not all code is shown here.